# Simple WYSIWGY CRUD web frontend for a database

Tags: web-apps, database, wysiwyg, database-browser

- It should be open source, deployable with MySQL/Postgres (or maybe some nosql thing);
- It should support CRUD using web forms;
- Layout of those forms should be configurable by administrator in the browser, in WYSIWYG way, like in Microsoft Access;
- It should support attachement of pictures. SVG support is very welcome.

Comment: Welcome, Vi. We could do with a lot more information than this. Please read [ask]. Must it be free, or do you have a budget? Can you give any more features which you would like. Which language are you coding in?

Comment: Basically I'm asking on behalf of other person, who has IT budget below 150 USD/month and obsolete hardware (it's a startup) and obviously prefers free solutions. He is'nt programmer at all, that's why he wants WYSIWYG.

Comment: If this is for external (customer) consumption then he should probably not be doing it himself. His product is almost certainly going to look amateurish. I recommend that he bite the bullet and invest in a programmer if he expects to make any money

Comment: @Mawg, He is trying to do IT himself _because of_ there is not enough budget for a sysadm/programmer.

Comment: I thought as much. It's going to be very tough for him. Perhaps he can find a programmer who will work for a small share of the company? I understand why he might be reluctant, but it might be the only way to realize his plans

Comment: He is not a director, he just knows a bit of IT, so the director dumped the IT to him. He is responsible and wants computers actually to help, not just hinder things like usual. Also it's not a big city, so can't easily hire some students.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say which language you are coding in. I will take a guess sand say it's PHP, as opposed to Node.Js or other.

If you code in PHP and don't mind using the veyy popular and easy to learn [CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/) framework, then you cannot beat [Grocery CRUD](http://www.grocerycrud.com/).

> grocery CRUD is an open source library that makes a developer's life
>   easier. Just few lines of code and you can create a full stable CRUD
>   with nice views. A completely automatic system that even a newbie in
>   PHP can work with.

You can add CRUD in 30 seconds - with a single line of code!  Plus it is endlessly customizable.

Take a look at [the examples](http://www.grocerycrud.com/examples).

For instance, with this code:

```
function my_boss_is_in_a_hurry()
{
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_table('customers');
    $crud->columns('customerName','phone','addressLine1','creditLimit');

    $output = $crud->render();

    $this->_example_output($output);
}
```

you get the slick output [shown here](http://www.grocerycrud.com/demo/my_boss_is_in_a_hurry)

[image]

Comment: I looked at the example for Invoices, and it shows the "header" data for the invoice, but not a sub-table for the line items on the same page. Does GroceryCRUD only do a 1:1 row-edit screen? Or could it show a row with related rows from another table?

Answer (score 1):

I like the Django Admin Interface.

In my case we use Django to create an maintain the database. The database schema migration support is great.

But I guess you already have a database schema.

Then the first step would be to create the Python models from the existing database. AFAIK there are tools which can help you to get this done.

It is open source and supports MySQL and PostgreSQL.

The form layout is not configurable via the web GUI. You need to modify some Python code.

Comment: Ultimately he (non-programmer startup person I'm asking on behalf of) wants the forms to follow some official document standard and be printable. But at first he just wants forms that are usuable by non-IT-professionals.

Comment: What is a "form" in this context?

Comment: A page with labels and input controls, allowing to view and edit a row in database table.

Comment: @vi. What kind if official documentation standard exists for such forms? I don't know any. And these, I call it, web input forms, should be printable? What is wrong with the output created by the browsers "print page" method?

Comment: Yes, he intends to use "print page" on such form later. But printing is currently out of scope, now just a database editor that works and evolves with no IT professionals around is needed.